# Laravel 9 withValidator $validator->fails() make server slow

Tags: php, laravel, request, backend, laravel-9

- PHP 8.1.4
- Apache/2.4.53
- Laravel Framework 9.33.0

I am trying to add messages error in every validation variable, searching and find this [withValidator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests)

```
// AccountRequest.php
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if ($this->request->has('modal') && $validator->fails()) {
            $validator->errors()->add('modal', $this->request->get('modal'));
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is everytime this code `$validator->fails()` running, my local server got so slow, and crash, even thought the `$request` is just 2 data

What I have done so far is, changing the server from using `php artisan serve` to `apache`

Edit,

This is error on apache log

```
[Sat Oct 29 21:02:42.135270 2022] [php:error] [pid 30872:tid 1896] [client 127.0.0.1:61836] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: what error you're getting?

Comment: error 500, its make my local server crash, `The page isn't working`

Comment: @Sumitkumar i updated the question, added apache log

Comment: can you tell if you're trying to return modal in case validator fails?

Comment: @Sumitkumar yes, im returning the modal Id if validator fails